# http2 clients such like nghttp, curl, stop sending more data to http2 server based on netty after stream has reached 64KB

Tags: netty, http2

The result of http2 request to netty (version: 4.1.31.Final) based server:

```
nghttp -v -n -H "http-rpc-type: JsonContent" -H "content-type: application/improved-json" -d 128k.json http://127.0.0.1:12220/com.arthur.HelloService/1.0.0/sayHello
[  0.002] Connected
[  0.002] send SETTINGS frame <length=12, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (niv=2)
          [SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS(0x03):100]
          [SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE(0x04):65535]
[  0.002] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=3>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=201, exclusive=0)
[  0.002] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=5>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=101, exclusive=0)
[  0.002] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=7>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.002] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=9>
          (dep_stream_id=7, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.002] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=11>
          (dep_stream_id=3, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.002] send HEADERS frame <length=126, flags=0x24, stream_id=13>
          ; END_HEADERS | PRIORITY
          (padlen=0, dep_stream_id=11, weight=16, exclusive=0)
          ; Open new stream
          :method: POST
          :path: /com.alibaba.arthur.hsf.HelloService/1.0.0/sayHello
          :scheme: http
          :authority: 127.0.0.1:12220
          accept: */*
          accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
          user-agent: nghttp2/1.32.0
          content-length: 393564
          http-rpc-type: JsonContent
          content-type: application/improved-json
[  0.002] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.002] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.002] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.003] send DATA frame <length=16383, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[ 10.006] send GOAWAY frame <length=8, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (last_stream_id=0, error_code=SETTINGS_TIMEOUT(0x04), opaque_data(0)=[])
Some requests were not processed. total=1, processed=0
```

The result of request to nghttp server is as follows, as we can see, the data is sent completely ending with the data frame which has END_STREAM flag. And the normal process has WINDOW_UPDATE frame, so I guess there are some problems with netty http2 server.

```
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (window_size_increment=32767)
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
          (window_size_increment=32767)
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=16383, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (window_size_increment=32768)
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
          (window_size_increment=32768)
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (window_size_increment=32767)
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
          (window_size_increment=32767)
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=16384, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=16383, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (window_size_increment=32768)
[  0.007] recv WINDOW_UPDATE frame <length=4, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
          (window_size_increment=32768)
[  0.007] send DATA frame <length=354, flags=0x01, stream_id=13>
          ; END_STREAM
```

Comment: NodeJS had a similar questsion: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16578

Comment: also what needy version ?

Comment: The version of netty is 4.1.31.Final and I use Http2ConnectionHandler implementation

Comment: The http2 server in netty works, but my implementation can't read more data when it  exceeds 64k. Do you have any suggestions to find the bugs?

Comment: maybe your implementation does not produce window update frames and so tell the remote peer that it is ready to consume more data ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have override `io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler#channelReadComplete` and didn't flush the window-update frame out

Comment: so you fixed now ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by not overriding `channelReadComplete` of `Http2ConnectionHandler`

Comment: ah yeah makes sense... if you override it you need to be sure you call `super.channelReadComplete`.